# How to set size of font with CSS without using - hyphen?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, visual-studio

I have been trying to set font size using following code:

```
.css({
       border:'0px', solid: '#f00', margin:'5px 0px',font-size: '14px'  
    })
```

But it doesnt work. Visual studio shows a red line and says it expects : where there is -

In fact I found out it doesnt even work on jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/17ed42pa/132/

Comment: Try using this: `css({
           'border' :'0px', 'color' :'#ff0' ,'margin' :'5px 0px',' font-size' : '14px'  
          })`

Comment: I think that the hyphen in that context interpeted as a minus, hence the IDE error and the fact it does not work in browser. You can probably use `fontSize` instead, which is incidentally used elsewhere in the example you linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work if you wrap `font-size` into quotes. By putting the value in quotes, it becomes a string.

```
.css({border:'0px', solid: '#f00', margin:'5px 0px','font-size': '14px'})
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/17ed42pa/134/)

Answer (score 1):

instead of `font-size` you should use `fontSize`

Answer (score 0):

You can try as follows.

```
// Setting CSS properties.

$( "h1" ).css( "fontSize", "100px" ); // Setting an individual property.

// Setting multiple properties.
$( "h1" ).css({
    fontSize: "100px",
    color: "red"
});
```

I have updated your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sibeeshvenu/17ed42pa/136/). Please check